# Timestamp.week vs. datetime.isocalendar

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I wonder why

```py
>>> pandas.Timestamp(dt.datetime(2009,1,6)).week
```

and

```py
>>> datetime.datetime(2009,1,6).isocalendar()[1]
```

don't give the same result.

Comment: pandas has no attribute 'Timestamp', nor does datetime... (what is `pd` and what is `dt`)?

Comment: >>>import pandas as pd
    >>> import datetime as dt

    >>>a=pd.Timestamp(dt.datetime(2009,1,7))
    >>>print a.isocalendar()[1]
print a.week

Answer (score 7):

First -- you need to get out of the habit of starting integers with `0`s.  This means they'll be interpreted as octal (base-8) constants, which leads to confusion:

```
>>> 10
10
>>> 010
8
```

As for why they give two different answers, there are two reasons:

(1) You're not comparing the week numbers.  As the documentation says, `isocalendar` "[r]eturn[s] a 3-tuple containing ISO year, week number, and weekday."  So `isocalendar()[2]` will give you the ISO weekday, not the week.

(2) ISO dates are defined a little differently than you might expect (explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)).  For example, in the most severe case:

```
>>> dt.datetime(2010,1,1).isocalendar()
(2009, 53, 5)
>>> pd.Timestamp(dt.datetime(2010,1,1)).week
1
```

so there will often be a difference.

Comment: Hello , thank you for your answer. I made a mistake when I wrote the question . I replace 2 by 1 in the isocalendar. the propriety week of TimeStamp is very strange . it gives 1 for the seven first day of 2009...I don't understand or I don't know exactly the meaning of timestamp.week

Comment: Is `Timestamp` new (to version 0.9)?

Comment: I use '0.8.1' . <class 'pandas.lib.Timestamp'>

Comment: @jfg I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Timestamp'` (for both `datetime` and `pandas`)... bizarre.